# determine the tense for "du unterrichtet worden bist"

Tags: tense

I was reading a Bible [here](http://www.schlachterbibel.de/de/bibel/lukas/1/1), and it contains the following sentence

> damit du die Gewißheit der Dinge erkennst, in denen du unterrichtet worden bist.

I am trying to understand, which tense is here and how it should be translated

> du bist unterrichtet worden

If does not look like passive in some tense, because passive should be constructed as `werden + Partizip II`, so I am lost... Can somebody explain all the steps which produce this sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know, passive present tense would be:

> Du wirst unterrichtet.

The past participle of “werden” **when used as an auxiliary verb** is “worden”, so this becomes in present perfect:

> Du bist unterrichtet worden.

Comment: According to https://www.verbformen.com/?w=werden Participle II for _werden_ is _geworden_, not _worden_. Why is _worden_ used?

Comment: @JohnSmith When used as auxiliary verb, _worden_ is the form to use, otherwise _geworden_.

Comment: @johnsmith, do not trust that site, some of the information there is just wrong.

Comment: @johnsmith The problem you seem to have is, that *unterrichtet* is the Partizip II you are searching. A second participle is simply wrong in  that sentence.

Comment: The difference between "worden" and "geworden" is worth to be added to the answer.